# django rest framework find url kwarg in APIView

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a url that looks like this:

```
url(r'^client_profile/address/(?P<id>.+)/$', views.ClientProfileAddressView.as_view())
```

And an APIView:

```
class ClientProfileAddressView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def put(self, request):
          ....

    def get(self, request):
          ....
```

In both `put` and `get`, I need to access the `id` url kwarg, the first one to update the object, the second to update it. How can I access the url argument in those methods?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work:

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      id = kwargs.get('id', 'Default Value if not there')

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      id = kwargs.get('id', 'Default Value if not there')
```

Comment: Can you also explain where this comes from and link to the documentation where it is explained? This information is hard to find in the docs as I don't know exactly what to look for (it is not on the Class-based Views page)

Comment: As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355860/2926992), one can get URL kwargs from the view object itself.

Comment: I think the OP, like me, was wondering how you discen this from the actual Django docs... so we can learn more related stuff...