# How to access url kwargs in generic API views (ListCreateAPIView to be more specific) in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to access url kwargs in generic API views (ListCreateAPIView to be more specific) in django rest framework, 
for example say I want to override the `get_queryset()` method inside a generic APIView class and I want it to use values as extracted from url kwargs, how would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Answers from **leelum1** and **aman kumar** helped me a lot, since I had the same question. I would add a particular example of how I used their answers. In the code below I try to obtain all the products that have as `category` attribute the same string passed on the `cat` variable from the url.

```
class ListProductsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(category=self.kwargs['cat'])
        return queryset
```

That solved my problem of filtering objects by using variables from the url.

Answer (score 2):

I spend a lot of time finding the answer to this question. Finally found it in my old written code. It works like a charm.

```
self.request.query_params.get('<name>')
```

I hope that is someone is still looking to get an answer this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access below like

```
def get_queryset(self):
     data = self.kwargs.get("key-name")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the get_queryset() method you can do something like this

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(parameter=self.kwargs['thing'])
    return queryset
```